# Left AirPod drops out after a few minutes of usage

Tags: airpods

I have the original [AirPods, 1st generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPods#1st_generation).

After many months of little use, I have started using them again with an Apple TV 4K and with the new iPhone SE 3rd Generation. In both situations, the left AirPod drops out, stops working. I can still hear through the right one.

If I put them away in the case, then retrieve them for usage again, both AirPods work immediately. But after 3-5 minutes, the left one disappears again while the right one continues working.

The battery shows as fully charged. Indeed, the odd thing is that I used to use the *right* AirPod a lot for phone calls, so I would expect its battery to be dying. But instead the right battery works well. It is the *left* AirPod, the less-used one, that is cutting out on me.

I have tried resetting the AirPods per [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209463). I have done this 3 times, where I choose to "forget this device", then hold down the back-side button until flashing amber then white, and re-pairing with the iPhone. Does not help. After several minutes of usage, the left one stops emitting sound.

Any other suggestions for resuscitating an absentee AirPod?